# How to turn back path levels?

Tags: python, django, path

i'm new in python world and i'm using python 3.4 and django 1.7
When o put `DEBUG=True` in *settings.py* the browser shows me an error like:

> Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
>   Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
>   C:\workspace_virtualenv34\prog\prog\templates\main_sites\registration\login.html (File does not exist)

But my templates are in a different path:

> C:\workspace_virtualenv34\prog\templates\

In *settings.py* i set ROOT_PATH as:

> ROOT_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname( **file** ), os.pardir))

Is there anyway to turn back path levels that solve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to provide any directories to `TEMPLATE_DIRS` that django will use to search for templates

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#template-dirs

you should be able to construct this using the `ROOT_PATH` to avoid referencing absolute paths directly; change for your specific path:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
  os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, '..', '..', 'prog', 'templates'
)
```